# Баскетбольное кольцо

Tags: c#, unity3d

Разрабатываю 2D игру на unity с баскетбольным кольцом, думаю как осуществить подсчёт очков.
У меня сейчас по одному коллайдеру на мяч и кольцо, но очки прибавляются и без пролёта в кольцо (когда мяч пролетает рядом).

---

Есть одна идея:

Сделать два коллайдера на кольце, чуть повыше и пониже, и один на мяче. Мяч пролетает верхний коллайдер, потом нижний, и очко засчитывается.

Только не пойму как закодить это. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Ты можешь сделать 2-а коллайдера на кольце: 1-ый отвечает за столкновения с кольцом (т.е. основной коллайдер (если у тебя 3д игра можно использовать MeshCollider)) и 2-ой внутри этого кольца в форме блина меньшего диаметра чем кольцо и сделать его IsTrigger (если игра 3д)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем повесить на кольцо скрипт, назовём его BasketballHoop и вызывать начисление очков в OnTriggerExit c предварительной проверкой прошёл ли шар через кольцо. Например так:

```
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
   {
        if (Vector3.Dot(gameObject.transform.up, other.gameObject.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position) > 0)
        {
            //не прошёл
        }
        else
        {
            //прошёл
        }
    }
```

То есть я беру скалярное произведение двух векторов

Какие преимущества данного решения:
 1. Можно использовать мяч любого размера
 2. Очки будут засчитываться только когда мяч попадает в кольцо сверху
    и, соответственно, не будут засчитываться если мяч попадает снизу
    или вылетает

Comment: Готов принимать критику. Не судите строго это мой первый ответ на данном сайте

Comment: Код текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ. Но на мой вкус перегружен. Решение замечательное, но человек начинает и ему нет нужны в `Vector3.Dot` ну и для многих слова `То есть я беру скалярное произведение двух векторов`
Могут быть страшными. Ответ однозначно заслужил плюс.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, поместить коллайдер кольца в центр кольца, мимо центра при попадании не пролетит

Answer (score 1):

В Unity есть **EdgeCollider2D**, который может помочь в этой ситуации. Если по бокам кольца разместить по **BoxCollider2D** небольшого размера, а между ними **EdgeCollider2D** - то получится избежать проблемы с прибавлением очков без пролёта в кольцо.

Должно получиться примерно, как на этом схематичном изображении:

[image: По бокам размещены BoxCollider2D, в центре EdgeCollider2D. Коллайдеры не пересекаются друг с другом.]

Можно разместить такой коллайдер непосредственно внутри кольца так, чтобы он был направлен "вверх" - это позволит реагировать на коллизию *только когда мяч будет "падать в кольцо сверху"*. Также следует поставить галочку на **IsTrigger**, чтобы коллайдер не останавливал мячик.

Чтобы отреагировать на коллизию с мячем используйте функцию **OnTriggerEnter()**, в которой и сделайте прибавление очков

Answer (score 1):

Код на мече. При выходе из коллайда проверяет ниже ли мяч, чем кольцо.

```
private void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D collision) {
    if (gameObject.transform.localPosition.y < collision.transform.localPosition.y) {
        // Goal
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лучше даже триггер чуть выше расположить.